# I am trying to add jquery file in my html file but its not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add Jquery slider in my html file, but I am facing the problem that some jquery functions are not being executed.

Here my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Aluminum and Glass</title>
<link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-   ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function slider()
 {
 $(".slider#1").show("fade",5000);
 }
</script>
<body>
<div id="wapper">

<div id="logo">
<img src="images/Logo.2cdr.jpg" width="948px" height="150" />
</div><!--end of logo -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The selector is wrong. Use `.slider` instead. Your selector `.slider#1` is trying to get all elements with class `slider` and id `1`

Comment: "some jquery functions"? Which ones?

Comment: If you look at  jQuery ui script src there is a large space in file name. That is not supposed to be there. Check your references paths.

Answer (score 2):

You have space in the src value

this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-   ui.min.js"></script>
```

replace with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```